# R how to draw ellipses and their axis (major and minor) over a chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce an existing chart with R and ggplot2. This chart has 3 ellipses for tolerance level (50% - 75% - 95%) with a specific angle. What I am able to do is to design the chart (x and y axis), but I am not able to reproduce the ellipses.
Here there is what I achieved:
[image: Chart made]

And here there is the code used to make this chart (i have a background image that helps me to know if I am close to the original chart).

```
ggplot() +  
  annotation_custom(imgonchart, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(rz,xc)) +
  geom_point(data=biadf, aes(mean(Rzm), mean(Xcm))) +
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 298.6, y0 = 30.8, a = 43, b = 8.9, angle = pi / 39.30 ), color="green") +
  coord_fixed(ratio=10)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,600), breaks = seq(0, 600, by= 50)) +  # set limit, steps, and how much can expand
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,60), breaks = seq(0, 60, 5)) +
  labs(x = expression(paste("Rz/H (", Omega, "/m)")), 
       y = expression(paste("Xc/H (", Omega, "/m)")),
       ) + # LEGENDA
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.minor.y =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) # to adjust the title in the middle
```

As you can see, the green ellipse (the more vivid one) is the one made by me. But when I try to rotate that ellipse, it goes out of the chart.
There is a scientific papers that describe how to design the above graph, here the text:

> Using the scale of Figure 1 for R/H and Xc/H, draw ellipses with major and minor axes slopes of 69.30° and -20.70° respectively. The semiaxes lenghts of the male panel ellipses are 89 and 43 Ohm/m for the 50% tolerance, 127 and 61 Ohm for the 75% tolerance and 187 and 89 Ohm/m for the 95% tolerance ellipses.

I was also trying to do it using the a "fake" sample like described in the paper with the rnorm() and the stat_ellipse(). But I was not able to reach the desired result.

Any help will be appreciated.
Marco

Comment: Could you please include data in your question so we can replicate this? The figures in your code and in the quote at the bottom don't match (89 vs 8.9), and there are several different ways this quote could be interpreted in light of the plot. A link to the original paper might be useful.  Also, your angle calculation is wrong (you can't covert degrees to radians by dividing by pi)

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you for the reply. I don't have any data, I'm trying to replicate that ellipses (that are derived from a bivariate distribution). Than I will use this chart as a base for a study of my sample. Here there is the link for the original paper: [link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Santi-Nigrelli/publication/15359286_Bivariate_normal_values_of_the_bioelectrical_impedance_vector_in_adult_and_elderly_populations/links/09e415100eb1e631af000000/Bivariate-normal-values-of-the-bioelectrical-impedance-vector-in-adult-and-elderly-populations.pdf). Problem seems to be in the angle.

Comment: @AllanCameron And 89 vs 8.9 is due to the `coord_fixed(ratio =10)` so I dived that value by 10. For the conversion from degree to radiant I was following the procedure in this page [link](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_ellipse.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to stick to the units used in the paper, and fake the axis instead by putting labels at 1/10th the value.

Starting with some dummy data for the `df` in your code, and converting the angle stated in the paper to radians, we have:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df        <- data.frame(rz = c(250, 300, 360), xc = c(35.1, 30.8, 34.8))
angle     <- -20.7
rad_angle <- angle / 180 * pi
```

And the plot would be:

```r
ggplot() +  
  coord_equal() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(rz, xc * 10)) +
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 298.6, y0 = 308, a = 5,  b = 10,  angle = rad_angle)) +
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 298.6, y0 = 308, a = 43, b = 89,  angle = rad_angle),
               color = 'green4') +
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 298.6, y0 = 308, a = 61, b = 127, angle = rad_angle),
               color = 'orange') +
  geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 298.6, y0 = 308, a = 89, b = 187, angle = rad_angle),
               color = 'red4') +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 298.6 - 89 * cos(rad_angle), 
                   xend = 298.6 + 89 * cos(rad_angle),
                   y = 308 - 89 * sin(rad_angle),
                   yend = 308 + 89 * sin(rad_angle)), linetype = 2, 
               color = 'gray50') +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 298.6 + 187 * sin(rad_angle), 
                   xend = 298.6 - 187 * sin(rad_angle),
                   y = 308 - 187 * cos(rad_angle),
                   yend = 308 + 187 * cos(rad_angle)), linetype = 2, 
               color = 'gray50') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,600), 
                     breaks = seq(0, 600, by = 50)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,600), 
                     breaks = seq(0, 600, 50), labels = ~.x/10) +
  labs(x = expression(paste("Rz/H (", Omega, "/m)")), 
       y = expression(paste("Xc/H (", Omega, "/m)"))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.minor.y =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I was guessing to change the scale, but not with this method. So, we can say that the problem was due to `coord_fixed(ratio=10)`. Your solution is simple, brilliant and useful. Thank you.